# Using Silverlight, how do I prompt the selected item's value on a SelectionChanged event?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, combobox

I can do this very easily on normal Combobox as SelectedText or SelectedValue, but using Silverlight, I can't get to that option.

Comment: Post some sample code, it increases your chances of getting a proper solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SelectedItem` property

Comment: SelectedItem give me the type, but not the value itself.

It returns me ComboBoxItem, that's not what I want.

Comment: It returns ComboBoxItem because you defined the items in your list as ComboBoxItems... if you define the content with the ItemsSource property, it will return the actual data items. How do you define the "value" of a ComboBoxItem anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection in conjunction with the DisplayMemberPath property:

```
var itemType = cbx.SelectedItem.GetType();
var pi = itemType.GetProperty(cbx.DisplayMemberPath);
var stringValue = pi.GetValue(cbx.SelectedItem, null).ToString();
```